# Puppet unable to send facts to Foreman - "tlsv1 alert unknown ca"

Tags: ssl, puppet, foreman

I recently updated *Katello* to *2.2* and *Foreman* now to *1.8.1*, so it appears somewhere in the upgrade that Puppet now cannot contact Foreman:

```
> [root@virt5 ~]# puppet agent --test info: 
> Retrieving plugin <snipped>
> err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
> SERVER: Failed when searching for node virt5: Failed to find virt5.
> via exec: Execution of '/etc/puppet/node.rb virt5' returned 1:
> warning: Not using cache on failed catalog err: Could not retrieve
> catalog; skipping run
```

When running the same command on my puppetmaster I see:

```
[root@foreman certs]# /etc/puppet/node.rb virt5
```

*Could not send facts to Foreman: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A: tlsv1 alert unknown ca*

I attempted to copy the */etc/pki/katello/certs/katello-default-ca.crt* certificate being used by httpd to */etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/* and then run `update-ca-trust extract`, but that does not appear to have made a difference.

I'm sure I'm missing something silly, I just am unsure as to what that would be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is stale, never had a good answer and is unlikely to be revived by the community.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake I'm seeing here (that should be clearer in the documentation) is that you believe that Katello uses the Puppet certificates like Foreman, but it doesn't.

On the Foreman/Katello host run:

```
capsule-certs-generate --capsule-fqdn "mycapsule.example.com"\ 
                       --certs-tar "~/mycapsule.example.com-certs.tar"
```

Where mycapsule.example.com is your other Puppet master.

Unpack that tarball and copy over the "puppet-client" certificate RPM to
   your Puppet master, and install it

Copy some files around:

```
cp /etc/pki/katello-certs-tools/certs/*-puppet-client.crt /etc/puppet/foreman.crt
cp /etc/pki/katello-certs-tools/private/*-puppet-client.key /etc/puppet/foreman.key
cd /etc/puppet
wget https://katello.mydomain.net/pub/katello-default-ca.crt
chown puppet /etc/puppet/foreman.{crt,key} /etc/puppet/katello*
```

Configure your /etc/puppet/foreman.yaml like this:

```
:url: "https://katello.mydomain.net"
:ssl_ca: "/etc/puppet/katello-default-ca.crt"
:ssl_cert: "/etc/puppet/foreman.crt"
:ssl_key: "/etc/puppet/foreman.key"
```

That should hopefully do it.

Comment: Hi! I followed what you said to do, but the same error occurs. I restarted puppet on the server just to be sure, but that didn't make a change.  
  
Both the /etc/puppet/foreman.{crt,key} files match those from /etc/pki/katello-certs-tools/ (via `diff`), and the /etc/puppet/foreman.yaml file correctly references those in the Puppet directory along with permissions having been set.

Is the /etc/pki/ca-trust folder touched the software at all? I copied both the Katello ca.crt and Puppet's .crt to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors and ran update-ca-trust, just in case too.